# XPath request matching with WireMock.net

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, wiremock

I want to send a mock response from my service when the request matches on these characteristics:

- URL matches with */BATConnectWS/services/CoverApplication*
- The HTTP method matches with `POST`
- The XPath matcher must match an amount of 5000

Code setup:

```
var server = FluentMockServer.Start(new FluentMockServerSettings
{
    Urls = new[] { "http://+:8099" },
    StartAdminInterface = true,
    Logger = new WireMockConsoleLogger()
});

server
    .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/*")).AtPriority(10)
    .RespondWith(Response.Create()
        .WithProxy("https://TheRealService.com/"));

server
    .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/BATConnectWS/services/CoverApplication").UsingPost()
    .WithBody(new XPathMatcher(@"//applyForCreditLimit/application/RequestedAmount/text() = 5000")))
    .AtPriority(1)
    .RespondWith(Response.Create()
    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
    .WithCallback(req =>
    {
        return CoverApplicationResponseBuilder.CreateResponse(req);
    }));
```

The request message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>urn:applyForCreditLimit</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:6da4a592-90a0-4623-8c71-1e685cbdac33</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:To>http://localhost:58070/BATConnectWS/services/CoverApplication</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6befddc7-4e4f-4a76-a203-49b729bd483a">
                <wsu:Created>2019-10-15T08:22:37Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2019-10-15T08:27:37Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-x-x-x-x-x">
                <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>xxx</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2019-10-15T08:22:37Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <applyForCreditLimit xmlns="http://atradius.com/connect/_2007_08/">
            <application>
                <CustomerId xmlns="">1234</CustomerId>
                <PolicyNr policyTypeIdentifier="NON_LEG" xmlns="">
                    <Id>5678</Id>
                </PolicyNr>
                <ExternalCoverId xmlns="">9101112</ExternalCoverId>
                <CustomerReference xmlns="">areference</CustomerReference>
                <Buyer registeredOffice="SYMPH" xmlns="">
                    <id xmlns="http://atradius.com/organisation/_2007_08/type/">13141516</id>
                    <countryTypeIdentifier xmlns="http://atradius.com/organisation/_2007_08/type/">AUT</countryTypeIdentifier>
                </Buyer>
                <RequestedAmount xmlns="">5000</RequestedAmount>
                <CurrencyCode xmlns="">EUR</CurrencyCode>
            </application>
        </applyForCreditLimit>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Without** the `XPathMatcher` the mocked response will be sent.
**With** the `XPatchMatcher` the real service will be called (pass through), because there was no *WithBody* match on the content.

What should the XPath query be like to match on the amount of 5000, in the `RequestedAmount` element?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the namespaces used maybe?

If you are only interested if any RequestedAmount element with value 5000 exists in the soap message, you could just use this I think:

```cs
@"//RequestedAmount/text() = 5000"
```